# IC / logo identification: 5.8 GHz radar MMIC marked "5810"

Tags: identification, radar

Can anyone identify the pictured IC or the manufacturer logo on it? It's a 5.8 GHz radar MMIC with 1 Tx, 1 Rx, PLL, power amplifier, mixer, and low noise amplifier, presumably from an Asian semiconductor company. It's in a 3x3 mm QFN package with 20 pins.

[image: IC marked 5810]

Comment: Not what you want - but liable to be of peripheral interest
https://www.novelic.com/norasens-radar-sensor-tehnology/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is manufacturured by a China company, called AirTouch.
Please visit below link for the detail, but I'm sorry it is in Chinese.

http://www.airtouching.com/?page_id=7255

Hard information online seems to be hard to find but it is a real product and a number of images and tables showing performance are avail;able on several sites.

---

[This news page](https://wemp.app/posts/416d5ca2-00ec-4414-b1c7-36e2934a65b3) says

- At present, the company mainly develops low-cost millimeter wave radar gesture recognition SoC chips and microwave radar sensing SoC chips for the smart home, energy-saving lighting and children’s toy markets, and provides a complete set of turnkey solutions (Turnkey Solutions) to help customers quickly develop "Black technology" intelligent electronic products of "air control objects".
- Its star product is the **microwave radar sensor chip AT5810**. Facing the field of smart lighting and smart home, it can sense the presence and movement of human bodies and objects. The chip works in the 5.8G ISM frequency band, which meets the certification requirements; the chip has a high degree of integration, and the sensor size is even smaller than a 5 dime coin.

Example images. These give an indication of frequency range and performance.

[image]

[image]